# Upload Attachment and some additional parameters to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC Controller with the following signature:-

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> SaveBrochureAsAttachment(Guid listingId, HttpPostedFileWrapper attachmentFile)
{
     ///some logic
}
```

How do I make an ajax call and send the file attachment and additional listingId parameter. Currently I am only able to send the attachment like this:-

```
var uploadFile = function () {

    if ($('#attachmentFile').val()) {

    }
    else {
        alert('No File Uploaded');
        return;
    }

    var formData = new FormData($('#uploadForm')[0]);


    $.ajax({
        url: '/Listing/SaveBrochureAsAttachment',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('File Uploaded');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#FileUpload").replaceWith($("#FileUpload").val('').clone(true));
            alert('File Uploaded Error');
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
}
```

Currently as you folks can see I am only able to send the attachment. How do I also send the Guid listingId to match the controller signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding another [formdata parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects):

```
formData.append("listingId", guidValue);
```

Provided you have the guid value accessible.  You can use [this to generate one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript) from the client.  Or create one from the server:

```
var guidValue = '@Guid.NewGuid()';
```

Comment: I also wrote about another alternative approach using the FileReader API; you can get the contents as a base64 string, which makes it easier to pass back to the server: https://onallthingsweb.wordpress.com/2017/06/26/ajax-file-uploads-with-html-5/

Answer (score 0):

one approach would be to your controller accept viewmodel (a class) which contains different property you need. and use formdata.append required stuff to post to the server.

On Server side; you will need to use modelbinder so that you will get required stuff populated.

Refernce for modelbinder : https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1261/custom-model-binder-aspnet-mvc

you can get more on google. :)